Android 14 Toast notifications - Oversized toast notification background
I'll explain quickly, recently installed a custom rom on my phone (Xiaomi) and has this enlarged toast notifications issue:

What I would like to know is how to "track down" what's causing it. What do I have to look for exactly to be able to fix this? Is there something like a parameter that can just wrap the background around the text?
I'm not really an Android developer, I'm learning Java and thought it'd be a fun activity for practicing.
Thanks in advance.
what I've tried so far is extracting SystemUI.apk from my phone via root explorer > decompile using apktool > search for any files that have to do with "toast", I think this is a bug in SystemUI app.
